# Terraform error when updating kubernetes_deployment

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I'm new to Terraform, and using it to create a Kubernetes cluster on GKE. I also want to create a Kubernetes deployment using the kubernetes_deployment resource type. This works perfectly, until I make a change to the deployment and run 'terraform apply' again. This results in the following error:

kubernetes_deployment.example: replicationcontrollers "terraform-example" not found

It looks like the Kubernetes provider starts looking for a replication controller to modify instead of a deployment. Am I doing something wrong, or might this be a bug in the provider?

I'm trying this with the following example: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/deployment.html

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a but there's already an issue open [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/210).

You can also see a gist with the logs [here](https://gist.github.com/enozero/9e60d362b7801b779555133241608059).

A deployment creates and managers a [ReplicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/) and not a [ReplicationController](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicationcontroller/). A replication controller is the older Kubernetes way of managing replicas and you may still some K8s resource definitions out there, and it's still supported. However, a lot of new management of stateless replicas has been centered mostly around Deployments/ReplicaSets.